# Return only one field in JSON data

Tags: python, json, django

I want to return only the `clandpin` fields. I have this model below:

model.py

```
class ButuanMaps(gismodel.Model):
class Meta:
    verbose_name = u'Butuan Map'
    verbose_name_plural = u'Butuan Maps'

clandpin = gismodel.CharField("Land PIN", max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
ssectionid = gismodel.ForeignKey(Section)
#ssectionid_id = gismodel.IntegerField()
geom = gismodel.MultiPolygonField("Geom ID", srid=32651, null=True, blank=True)
objects = gismodel.GeoManager()

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.clandpin
```

In my template, here's the code for AJAX:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#formsection").change(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url : "/sectionpins",
            type : "GET",
            dataType: "html",
            data : {
                'sectionid' : $('#formsection').val(),
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
            },
            success : searchSuccess,
            error: errs
        });
    return false;
    });
});
function searchSuccess(data){
    alert("Success");
    $('#forminput').append(
            "<option value='"+data+"'>"+data+"</option>"
    );
}
function errs(){
    alert('Error!!!!');
}
</script>
```

In views.py:

```
    def section_landpins(request):
if request.method == "GET":
    m = ButuanMaps.objects.filter(ssectionid=request.GET['sectionid'])
    landpins = serializers.serialize("json", m.values('clandpin'), fields=("clandpin"))
    data = json.dumps({
        'pins': landpins,
    })
    return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

It returned an error

```
 AttributeError at /sectionpins'dict' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

When I changed the query with this:

```
 m = ButuanMaps.objects.filter(ssectionid=request.GET['sectionid'])
```

It doesn't return an error but this:

```
{"pins": "[{\"pk\": 185625, \"model\": \"tbl.butuanmaps\", \"fields\": {\"clandpin\": \"162-12-0001-055-37\"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by requesting only the field you are interested in from the ORM, then evaluating the ValueQuerySet into a list of dictionaries:

```
section_id = request.GET.get('sectionid', 'defaultid')

m = ButuanMaps.objects.filter(ssectionid=section_id).values('landpins')
return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'pins': list(m)}),
                               content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: Will you please explain this part of code: `section_id = request.GET.get('ssectionid', 'defaultid`